# GUI elements still visible after setting alpha to 0

Tags: android, android-activity

I've got a `Button` and some text and am setting their alphas to 0 within the `Activity`s `onCreate()`. However when the `Activity` displays these items are still visible.

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TURN ON ACCESS"
    android:onClick="launchNotificationAccess"
    android:id="@+id/notificationAccessButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:background="#ff93c5ff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/notificationAccessText"
    android:text="Message about notification access placeholder"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notificationAccessButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

`onCreate()` code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    View notificationAccessMessage = this.findViewById(R.id.notificationAccessText);
    notificationAccessMessage.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    View notificationAccessButton = this.findViewById(R.id.notificationAccessButton);
    notificationAccessButton.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make both the Button and the Edittext invisible I would use the function setVisibility like so

```
notificationAccessMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
notificationAccessButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use alpha for hiding a view, then it makes sense to use animation.

```
notificationAccessMessage
    .animate()             // animate
        .alpha(0f)         // to alpha = 0f
        .setDuration(300)  // in 300 ms
        .withEndAction(new Runnable {
            @Override public void run() {
                // set alpha back to 1f and hide view after animation ends
                notificationAccessMessage.setAlpha(1f);
                notificationAccessMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Otherwise simply use `setVisiblity()` method.

```
notificationAccessMessage.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
```